# How to force LocalDB to use a certain version

Tags: localdb, sql-server-2016

On my machine I've installed LocalDb 2012, 2014 and 2016. When I run my application it won't pick the latest version by default.

The used connection string:

`Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ServiceLocal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=5`

So I use 'MSSQLLocalDB' (instead of v11.0). But it won't run 2016, but 2014 (i.e 12.0.2000.8). It doesn't work to choose v13.0. So what else can I do?

Comment: Have you tried using the "sqllocladb" command line tool to delete and re-create the mssqllocaldb instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand the concepts. Each instance is really an instance. The connection string targets such an instance, so to get another version you either create a new instance with that version. In the case of MSSqlLocalDb, delete the instance and it will be automatically recreated when queried using the lastest installed version of LocalDb

Answer (score 7):

Recreating the instance as explained by Gabriël works but may not be an option. In the typical example, you want to create/attach a database on a client machine where you should not mess with existing instances.

Facing the same problem, I decided the best workaround was to start my application by script and create my own instance using SqlLocalDB.exe in the desired version before starting my application:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "MyVeryOwnInstance" 13.0 -s
```

The -s flag causes the instance to be started immediately. Afterwards in your application you can connect with:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MyVeryOwnInstance;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ServiceLocal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=5
```

This of course requires that the desired version is installed. I ensured this by bundling it with my applications installer.